# Maximum sum rectangle in a 2D matrix PYTHON

Tags: python, algorithm, solution

As title says i'm looking for solution of maximum sum rectangle in a 2d matrix in python, but im not intereseted in Kadanes algorithm, im looking for so called "naive solution" with many loops. How to do that ?

Comment: Loop through all matrices, store the sum and only assign it a new maximum if it is larger compared to the stored sum?

Comment: i got the idea, but i had a problem implementing it, would you be able to show me working code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the naive algorithm: there are 4 variables that determine a submatrix: its

- top row
- left column
- bottom row
- right column

So that means you'll have four nested loops to find all possible combinations of these parameters.

Then, for each of those submatrixes you calculate the sum. This means you will visit each cell in each submatrix. You'll have a loop over:

- each row in the submatrix
- each column in the submatrix

So in total you'll have 6 loops. It looks like this:

```
m = [
    [ 1,  2, -1, -4, -20],
    [-8, -3,  4,  2,   1],
    [ 3,  8, 10,  1,   3],
    [-4, -1,  1,  7,  -6]
]

maxsum = 0
for top in range(0, len(m)):
    for left in range(0, len(m[0])):
        for bottom in range(top, len(m)):
            for right in range(left, len(m[0])):
                thissum = 0
                for row in range(top, bottom+1):
                    for col in range(left, right+1):
                        thissum += m[row][col]
                maxsum = max(thissum, maxsum)
print(maxsum)  # 29
```

Comment: This works but not very efficient?  This solution requires 6 nested loops –  

4 for start and end coordinate of the 2 axis O(n ** 4)
and 2 for the summation of the sub-matrix O(n ** 2).
The overall time complexity of this solution would be O(n**6).

Comment: @DanielHao, indeed, but that is exactly what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Got the point.  Very interesting... Thanks.